# iPhone not seeing gin-gonic cookie

Tags: go, go-gin

My platform works fine on andriod and pc browsers. But when I try making a requests on iPhone, it returns `http: named cookie not present`

I'm using gin-gonic framework to set the cookie and everything works fine as expected unless iPhone or probably iOS and apple devices

```
c.SetSameSite(http.SameSiteNoneMode)
c.SetCookie("token", personToken, int(time.Now().Add(7*24*time.Hour).Unix()), "/", "", true, true)
c.SetCookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, int(time.Now().Add(7*24*time.Hour).Unix()), "/", "", true, true)
c.SetCookie("logged_in", "true", int(time.Now().Add(7*24*time.Hour).Unix()), "/", "", true, false)
```

This is the code that sets the cookie. I'm using free hosting for testing, I've tested on andriod, it works as expected, but iPhone is not receiving the cookie, and from my code, everything looks fine

Comment: Edit the question to show the code that sets the cookie.  Describe the URL where the cookie set, the URL where you expect to receive the cookie, and the specific browser where. you observed the problem.